# Hungarian Algorithm: How to cover 0 elements with minimum lines?

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, hungarian-algorithm

I am trying to implement the Hungarian algorithm in Java. I have an NxN cost matrix. I am following [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Hungarian-Algorithm) guide step by step. So I have the costMatrix[N][N] and 2 arrays to track covered rows and covered cols - rowCover[N], rowColumn[N]  (1 means covered, 0 means uncovered)

How can I cover the 0s with the minimum number of lines? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the 3rd step of the algorithm in the [Wikipedia article (section *Matrix Interpretation*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_interpretation) , they explain a way to compute the minimal amount of lines to cover all the 0's

**Update:** The following is another way to obtain the minimum number of lines that cover the `0's`:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MinLines { 
    enum LineType { NONE, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL }

    private static class Line {
        int lineIndex;
        LineType rowType;
        Line(int lineIndex, LineType rowType) { 
            this.lineIndex = lineIndex;
            this.rowType = rowType;
        }      
        LineType getLineType() {
            return rowType;
        }

        int getLineIndex() { 
            return lineIndex; 
        }
        boolean isHorizontal() {
            return rowType == LineType.HORIZONTAL;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isZero(int[] array) {
        for (int e : array) {
            if (e != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static List<Line> getMinLines(int[][] matrix) {
        if (matrix.length != matrix[0].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix should be square!");
        }

        final int SIZE = matrix.length;
        int[] zerosPerRow = new int[SIZE];
        int[] zerosPerCol = new int[SIZE];

        // Count the number of 0's per row and the number of 0's per column        
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) { 
                if (matrix[i][j] == 0) { 
                    zerosPerRow[i]++;
                    zerosPerCol[j]++;
                }
            }
        }

        // There should be at must SIZE lines, 
        // initialize the list with an initial capacity of SIZE
        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>(SIZE);

        LineType lastInsertedLineType = LineType.NONE;

        // While there are 0's to count in either rows or colums...
        while (!isZero(zerosPerRow) && !isZero(zerosPerCol)) { 
            // Search the largest count of 0's in both arrays
            int max = -1;
            Line lineWithMostZeros = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                // If exists another count of 0's equal to "max" but in this one has
                // the same direction as the last added line, then replace it with this
                // 
                // The heuristic "fixes" the problem reported by @JustinWyss-Gallifent and @hkrish
                if (zerosPerRow[i] > max || (zerosPerRow[i] == max && lastInsertedLineType == LineType.HORIZONTAL)) {
                    lineWithMostZeros = new Line(i, LineType.HORIZONTAL);
                    max = zerosPerRow[i];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                // Same as above
                if (zerosPerCol[i] > max || (zerosPerCol[i] == max && lastInsertedLineType == LineType.VERTICAL)) {
                    lineWithMostZeros = new Line(i, LineType.VERTICAL);
                    max = zerosPerCol[i];
                }
            }

            // Delete the 0 count from the line 
            if (lineWithMostZeros.isHorizontal()) {
                zerosPerRow[lineWithMostZeros.getLineIndex()] = 0; 
            } else {
                zerosPerCol[lineWithMostZeros.getLineIndex()] = 0;
            }

            // Once you've found the line (either horizontal or vertical) with the greater 0's count
            // iterate over it's elements and substract the 0's from the other lines 
            // Example:
            //                          0's x col:
            //           [ 0  1  2  3 ]  ->  1
            //           [ 0  2  0  1 ]  ->  2
            //           [ 0  4  3  5 ]  ->  1
            //           [ 0  0  0  7 ]  ->  3
            //             |  |  |  | 
            //             v  v  v  v
            // 0's x row: {4} 1  2  0 

            //           [ X  1  2  3 ]  ->  0
            //           [ X  2  0  1 ]  ->  1
            //           [ X  4  3  5 ]  ->  0
            //           [ X  0  0  7 ]  ->  2
            //             |  |  |  | 
            //             v  v  v  v
            //            {0} 1  2  0 

            int index = lineWithMostZeros.getLineIndex(); 
            if (lineWithMostZeros.isHorizontal()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    if (matrix[index][j] == 0) {
                        zerosPerCol[j]--;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    if (matrix[j][index] == 0) {
                        zerosPerRow[j]--;
                    }
                }                    
            }

            // Add the line to the list of lines
            lines.add(lineWithMostZeros); 
            lastInsertedLineType = lineWithMostZeros.getLineType();
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) { 
        int[][] example1 = 
        { 
           {0, 1, 0, 0, 5},
           {1, 0, 3, 4, 5},
           {7, 0, 0, 4, 5},
           {9, 0, 3, 4, 5},
           {3, 0, 3, 4, 5} 
        };

        int[][] example2 = 
        {
           {0, 0, 1, 0},
           {0, 1, 1, 0},
           {1, 1, 0, 0},
           {1, 0, 0, 0},
        };

        int[][] example3 = 
        {
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
           {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        };

        List<int[][]> examples = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
        examples.add(example1);
        examples.add(example2);
        examples.add(example3);

        for (int[][] example : examples) {
            List<Line> minLines = getMinLines(example);
            System.out.printf("Min num of lines for example matrix is: %d\n", minLines.size());
            printResult(example, minLines);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void printResult(int[][] matrix, List<Line> lines) {
        if (matrix.length != matrix[0].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix should be square!");
        }

        final int SIZE = matrix.length;
        System.out.println("Before:");
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (Line line : lines) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                int index = line.getLineIndex();
                if (line.isHorizontal()) {
                    matrix[index][i] = matrix[index][i] < 0 ? -3 : -1;
                } else {
                    matrix[i][index] = matrix[i][index] < 0 ? -3 : -2;
                }
            }
        }   

        System.out.println("\nAfter:");
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%s ", matrix[i][j] == -1 ? "-" : (matrix[i][j] == -2 ? "|" : (matrix[i][j] == -3 ? "+" : Integer.toString(matrix[i][j]))));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

The important part is the `getMinLines` method, it returns a `List` with the lines that cover the matrix `0's` entries. For the example matrices prints:

```
Min num of lines for example matrix is: 3
Before:
0 1 0 0 5 
1 0 3 4 5 
7 0 0 4 5 
9 0 3 4 5 
3 0 3 4 5 

After:
- + - - - 
1 | 3 4 5 
- + - - - 
9 | 3 4 5 
3 | 3 4 5 

Min num of lines for example matrix is: 4
Before:
0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 0 
1 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 

After:
| | | | 
| | | | 
| | | | 
| | | | 

Min num of lines for example matrix is: 6
Before:
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 

After:
- - - - - - 
- - - - - - 
- - - - - - 
- - - - - - 
- - - - - - 
- - - - - -
```

I hopes this give you a boost, the rest of the Hungarian algorithm shouldn't be hard to implement

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful and very clear. Definitely gives me a boost. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Assuming that lineWithMostZeros returns just some arbitrary line this may not work. Consider for example the matrix: `0010 0110 1100 1000` Your code will first choose column 4 (with four zeros) but then perhaps the next line it chooses is row 1 (with two remaining zeros) followed by row 4 (with two remaining zeros) and then row 2 (with one remaining zero) followed by row 3 (with one remaining zero) giving a total of five lines.

Comment: @JustinWyss-Gallifent is right. This method was very similar to the one I independently implemented and tested (before looking in stackoverflow for an alternate solution!).
Try this one http://www.netlib.org/utk/lsi/pcwLSI/text/node222.html

Comment: @JustinWyss-Gallifent sorry for the delay to answer, I've made some adjustments to the algorithm, basically added a heuristic to keep searching for rows or columns with the same direction of the last line pushed. Please, if you find another test case that make this fail, report it so I can improve the algorithm or discard it

Comment: @hkrish see comment above, I made some minor adjustments, sorry for answering this late

Comment: If I can cover out the zeros left in the matrix after step one in more than one way, could I choose one of that ways arbitrarily?

Comment: With the below table as input, the function returns 9...when it should return 8. Not sure yet what the bug is, but I will update with a new algorithm when I find out. Input: --> ```[[0,94,2,91,57,0,115,2,99],
[113,19,7,32,42,13,0,35,16],
[109,11,31,56,38,29,16,31,0],
[81,51,39,0,10,37,24,67,40],
[94,0,34,59,23,42,27,30,11],
[71,37,39,0,0,47,32,71,48],
[71,41,43,4,0,43,28,71,44],
[80,110,0,153,137,0,113,0,97],
[0,94,0,89,57,8,121,0,105]]``` . Output --> 9 . Correct output --> 8

Comment: Indeed, this answer is incorrect, it uses a greedy approach which is not correct for this problem. As the author, I would like to delete this post but I can't because is marked as "Answer" :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been solved long time ago, but I would like to share my implementation for the step 3 where minimum lines should be drawn in a way that all zeros are covered.

Here's a brief explanation on how my algorithm for this step works:

- Loop on all cells, the cell that has a value zero, we need to draw a line passing by it, and its neighbours
- To know in which direction the line should be drawn, I created a method called maxVH() that will count the zeros vertically vs horizontally, and returns an integer. If the integer is positive, draw a vertical line, else if zero or negative, draw a horizontal line.
- colorNeighbors() method will draw the lines and will count them as well. Moreover, it will place 1 on the elements where the line passes vertically. -1 on the elements where the line passes horizontally. 2 on the elements where 2 intersecting lines passes (horizontal and vertical).

The advantage of having those 3 methods is that we know the elements that are covered twice, we know which elements are covered, and which are not covered. In addition, while drawing the lines, we increment the number of line counter.

For the full implementation of the Hungarian Algorithm + Example: [**Github**](https://github.com/amirbawab/Hungarian-Algorithm)

**Code + Detailed Comments for step 3**:

```
/**
     * Step 3.1
     * Loop through all elements, and run colorNeighbors when the element visited is equal to zero
     * */
    public void coverZeros(){
        numLines = 0;
        lines = new int[values.length][values.length];

        for(int row=0; row<values.length;row++){
            for(int col=0; col<values.length;col++){
                if(values[row][col] == 0)
                    colorNeighbors(row, col, maxVH(row, col));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Step 3.2
     * Checks which direction (vertical,horizontal) contains more zeros, every time a zero is found vertically, we increment the result
     * and every time a zero is found horizontally, we decrement the result. At the end, result will be negative, zero or positive
     * @param row Row index for the target cell
     * @param col Column index for the target cell
     * @return Positive integer means that the line passing by indexes [row][col] should be vertical, Zero or Negative means that the line passing by indexes [row][col] should be horizontal
     * */
    private int maxVH(int row, int col){
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<values.length;i++){
            if(values[i][col] == 0)
                result++;
            if(values[row][i] == 0)
                result--;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Step 3.3
     * Color the neighbors of the cell at index [row][col]. To know which direction to draw the lines, we pass maxVH value.
     * @param row Row index for the target cell
     * @param col Column index for the target cell
     * @param maxVH Value return by the maxVH method, positive means the line to draw passing by indexes [row][col] is vertical, negative or zero means the line to draw passing by indexes [row][col] is horizontal
     * */
    private void colorNeighbors(int row, int col, int maxVH){
        if(lines[row][col] == 2) // if cell is colored twice before (intersection cell), don't color it again
            return;

        if(maxVH > 0 && lines[row][col] == 1) // if cell colored vertically and needs to be recolored vertically, don't color it again (Allowing this step, will color the same line (result won't change), but the num of line will be incremented (wrong value for the num of line drawn))
            return;

        if(maxVH <= 0 && lines[row][col] == -1) // if cell colored horizontally and needs to be recolored horizontally, don't color it again (Allowing this step, will color the same line (result won't change), but the num of line will be incremented (wrong value for the num of line drawn))
            return;

        for(int i=0; i<values.length;i++){ // Loop on cell at indexes [row][col] and its neighbors
            if(maxVH > 0)   // if value of maxVH is positive, color vertically
                lines[i][col] = lines[i][col] == -1 || lines[i][col] == 2 ? 2 : 1; // if cell was colored before as horizontal (-1), and now needs to be colored vertical (1), so this cell is an intersection (2). Else if this value was not colored before, color it vertically
            else            // if value of maxVH is zero or negative color horizontally
                lines[row][i] = lines[row][i] == 1 || lines[row][i] == 2 ? 2 : -1; // if cell was colored before as vertical (1), and now needs to be colored horizontal (-1), so this cell is an intersection (2). Else if this value was not colored before, color it horizontally
        }

        // increment line number
        numLines++;
//      printMatrix(lines); // Monitor the line draw steps
    }//End step 3
```

Comment: This implementation also does not work for soem cases. Try running this:   int[][] values = { 
  { 17 ,  10 ,  13 ,   2 ,  12 ,  11 ,  0 },
  { 5 ,   8 ,   9 ,  0 ,   3 ,   5 ,   5 },
  { 0 ,   2 ,   0 ,   6 ,   9 ,   8 ,  13 },
  { 26 ,   1 ,  11 ,  12 ,  0 ,   0 ,  13 },
  { 17 ,  0 ,  20 ,  17 ,  25 ,  25 ,  23 },
  { 0 ,   0 ,   4 ,   0 ,  10 ,  11 ,   0 },
  { 12 ,  11 ,  0 ,  20 ,  12 ,   6 ,  14 }
  };

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement on @higuaro's answer, but in Swift (works for
`[[0,94,2,91,57,0,115,2,99],[113,19,7,32,42,13,0,35,16],[109,11,31,56,38,29,16,31,0],[81,51,39,0,10,37,24,67,40],[94,0,34,59,23,42,27,30,11],[71,37,39,0,0,47,32,71,48],[71,41,43,4,0,43,28,71,44],[80,110,0,153,137,0,113,0,97],[0,94,0,89,57,8,121,0,105]]`
):

```
func modifiedGetMinLines(_ matrix: [[Int]]) -> Set<Line> { // O(N^4)
    
    // Using the algorithm found here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrfFTdO2Z7I
    func drawLinesWhileIsolatedZerosExist(_ matrix: inout [[Int]]) -> Set<Line> { // O(N^3)
        
        let N = matrix.count
        
        var lines: Set<Line> = []
        var unprocessedTableChange = true
        while unprocessedTableChange { // While loop occurs 2N-1 times max!...each time a line in a matrix must be crossed out to continue
            unprocessedTableChange = false
            
            for i in 0..<N { // rows
                var zeroCount = 0
                var columnOfLastZero = -1
                for j in 0..<N {
                    if matrix[i][j] == 0 {
                        zeroCount += 1
                        columnOfLastZero = j
                    }
                }
                
                if zeroCount == 1 {
                    unprocessedTableChange = true
                    
                    var selectedCol = Line(columnOfLastZero, .VERTICAL)
                    for i in 0..<N {
                        if matrix[i][columnOfLastZero] == 0 {
                            selectedCol.coord.insert(i)
                        }
                        matrix[i][columnOfLastZero] = -1 // Cross line out
                    }
                    lines.insert(selectedCol)
                }
            }
            
            for i in 0..<N { // columns
                var zeroCount = 0
                var rowOfLastZero = -1
                for j in 0..<N {
                    if matrix[j][i] == 0 {
                        zeroCount += 1
                        rowOfLastZero = j
                    }
                }
                
                if zeroCount == 1 {
                    unprocessedTableChange = true
                    
                    var selectedRow = Line(rowOfLastZero, .HORIZONTAL)
                    for i in 0..<N {
                        if matrix[rowOfLastZero][i] == 0 {
                            selectedRow.coord.insert(i)
                        }
                        matrix[rowOfLastZero][i] = -1 // Cross line out
                    }
                    lines.insert(selectedRow)
                }
            }
        }
        
        return lines
    }
    
    func zerosToProcessExist(_ array: [Int]) -> Bool { // O(N)
        for e in array {
            if e > 0 { return true }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    var matrix = matrix
    let N = matrix.count
    var lines: Set<Line> = drawLinesWhileIsolatedZerosExist(&matrix) // O(N^3)
    var zerosPerRow = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
    var zerosPerCol = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)

    for i in 0..<N { // O(N^2)
        for j in 0..<N {
            if matrix[i][j] == 0 {
                zerosPerRow[i] += 1
                zerosPerCol[j] += 1
            }
        }
    }

    while zerosToProcessExist(zerosPerRow) || zerosToProcessExist(zerosPerCol) { // While loop occurs 2N-1 times max!...each time a line in a matrix must be crossed out to continue
        
        var max = 0
        var lineWithMostZeros: Line?
        
        var linesWithMaxZeros: Set<Line> = []
        for i in 0..<N { // O(N)
            if zerosPerRow[i] > max {
                linesWithMaxZeros = []
                linesWithMaxZeros.insert(Line(i, LineType.HORIZONTAL))
                max = zerosPerRow[i]
            } else if zerosPerRow[i] == max && max > 0 {
                linesWithMaxZeros.insert(Line(i, LineType.HORIZONTAL))
            }
            
            if zerosPerCol[i] > max {
                linesWithMaxZeros = []
                linesWithMaxZeros.insert(Line(i, LineType.VERTICAL))
                max = zerosPerCol[i]
            } else if zerosPerCol[i] == max && max > 0 {
                linesWithMaxZeros.insert(Line(i, LineType.VERTICAL))
            }
        }

        if linesWithMaxZeros.count == 1 {
            lineWithMostZeros = linesWithMaxZeros.first
        } else {
            var minScore = Int.max
            var minScoreLine: Line?
            for l in linesWithMaxZeros {
                var score = 0
                if l.isHorizontal() {
                    for j in 0..<N {
                        if matrix[l.lineIndex][j] == 0 {
                            for k in 0..<N {
                                if matrix[k][j] == 0 { score += 1 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for j in 0..<N {
                        if matrix[j][l.lineIndex] == 0 {
                            for k in 0..<N {
                                if matrix[j][k] == 0 { score += 1 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if score < minScore {
                    minScore = score
                    minScoreLine = l
                }
            }
            lineWithMostZeros = minScoreLine
        }
        
        let index = lineWithMostZeros!.lineIndex
        var temp: Set<Int> = []
        if lineWithMostZeros!.isHorizontal() { // O(N)
            zerosPerRow[index] = 0
            for j in 0..<N {
                if matrix[index][j] == 0 {
                    zerosPerCol[j] -= 1
                    temp.insert(j)
                }
                matrix[index][j] = -1
            }
        } else {
            zerosPerCol[index] = 0
            for j in 0..<N {
                if matrix[j][index] == 0 {
                    zerosPerRow[j] -= 1
                    temp.insert(j)
                }
                matrix[j][index] = -1
            }
        }
        lineWithMostZeros!.coord = temp
        lines.insert(lineWithMostZeros!)
    }
    return lines
}
```