# Minimum lines for Hungarian Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, hungarian-algorithm

I want to know the minimum number of lines covering all the Zeros for Hungarian Algorithm.
Ive followed this link, but the code there is a greedy one.

[Hungarian Algorithm: How to cover 0 elements with minimum lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795111/hungarian-algorithm-how-to-cover-0-elements-with-minimum-lines)

For example,

```
{0,0,1,1},
{1,0,0,1},
{1,0,1,0},
{1,1,1,1},
```

This case fails. I should get output 3. But the output this solution gives is 4.

Any other ways of solving it would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ I think this question would be more relevant there.

Comment: @dmi3y I doubt it. Code Golf is for writing a program with as few lines as possible, or that executes as fast as possible. Not for general approaches to algorithm questions.

Comment: yes, TS mentioned minimum lines of algorithm, that's why I thought it might be more help on Code Golf than here on SF.

Comment: @dmi3y you misunderstood the question. The OP wants to cover the 0s with a miniumum number of lines. See [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @kinokijuf, thanks, yes I could see now I am wrong, but still not quite understand what is minimum number of lines?

Comment: @pathikrit, there are so many better resources for the Hungarian algorithm...

Comment: @pathikrit What should be the language? is there a defference between cpp, js, java for you?

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

I didn't have access to a CPP compiler or java runtime. Wrote this using my browser using ES2017. At least it runs in your browser! If you need I can write it in other languages (cpp, java, php, python).

And I must add that I don't know anything about `Hungarian Algorithm` and I just created an algorithm to find the best minimum optimized lines!

I'm pushing this code and tests in a [Github repo](https://github.com/alijvhr/HungarianAlgorithm). So you can fire more Info, Codes, Documentations [here](https://github.com/alijvhr/HungarianAlgorithm)

In matrix data presentation I used:

**index `0` represents rows and index `1` represents columns.**

### Step 1

Go through `input` array and count the zeros and store it in a 2 dimensional array.

The `#matrixPower` indicates number of zeros in each column or row.

### Step 2

In the next step we check row by row. Each row which have a value greater than `0` in `#matrixPower[0]` is a row contains zeros and we call them `powered` from now on.

Loop through powered row and check every column which crosses the current `powered` row on `0`! If there was any column with power of `1` so we draw the line on the row! And decrease the power of every crossed column by `1`. Because it is covered by current row!

Count the lines in the progress.

Do this for all rows!

**Notice:** When a column crosses a row on a `zero` the power would be at least `1` because of the `zero` in the cross!

### Step 3

If any `powered` column remains we should draw the line on them!

That's it! now we have a map of lines and a number of minimum lines!

**Note: `inputMatrix` is the variable which contains your matrix!**

```js
let colLength = inputMatrix[0].length;
let rowLength = inputMatrix.length;
let matrixPower = [Array(rowLength).fill(0), Array(colLength).fill(0)];
let matrixLine = [Array(rowLength).fill(0), Array(colLength).fill(0)];

for (let row = 0; row < rowLength; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < colLength; col++) {
        if (inputMatrix[row][col] == 0) {
            matrixPower[0][row]++;
            matrixPower[1][col]++;
        }
    }
}
let minimum = 0;
let len = [matrixPower[0].length, matrixPower[1].length], cross;
for (let row = 0; row < len[0]; row++) {
    cross = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < len[0]; col++) {
        if (inputMatrix[row][col] == 0) {
            cross.push(col);
            if (matrixPower[1][col] < 2) {
                matrixLine[0][row] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (matrixLine[0][row] == 1) {
        minimum++;
        for (let i = 0; i < cross.length; i++)
            matrixPower[1][cross[i]]--;
    }
}
for (let col = 0; col < len[1]; col++) {
    if (matrixPower[1][col] > 0) {
        matrixLine[1][col] = 1;
        minimum++;
    }
}

console.log(minimum);
```

I tested the algorithm against an optimized brute force function 100 times with random `12*10` matrixes. The result was 100% OK!

> **average time of brute force: 0.036653s**
>
> **average time of Optimized algorithm: 0.000019s**

> **total time of brute force: 3.9180s**
>
> **total time of Optimized algorithm: 0.0025s**

I hundred tests brute force took **~4seconds** but the algorithm took only **2.5milliseconds**

I'm sure this can be more optimized through more work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it is indeed correct - perhaps you can write a brute force solution checked which tries all possible 2^(row + column) ways by drawing all possible lines and sees if it works or not against your solution.

Comment: Also, for the sake of clarification for other readers, can you explain this part better "If a line zeros was covered by other lines in opposite direction the line will marked for removing. However if any of lines in opposite direction which is covering a zero from current line does not contain another zero, current line will be preserved and opposite line will be marked for removing."? I think I know what you mean - remove any lines which are not needed because its work is done by other lines but how do you pick which one is the redundant one - this one or the other one?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I will elaborate more in 2-3 hours. Actually I was sleepy during answering, so it might be a little unclear.